# Why don't we use the .class extension with "java" command?

Tags: java

Why don't we give the `filename.class` file after `java` command, instead of only `filename`?

Suppose we want to compile the `test.java` program, then we run `javac test.java`. It is  ok!

After that it will produce `test.class` file but to run the program we run `java test` instead of `java test.class`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Ultimately, because that's the way it's designed.  It could have been designed differently, but, as the answers below suggest, tacking on ".class" would have confused package name parsing and no doubt several other things.  There's never a "logical" design for such things, just some designs that are less illogical than others.

Answer (score 19):

Because you are not describing a *file* to run.  You are telling Java which *class* contains the main method - and the class' name is (in your case) `filename`, not `filename.class`.

The fact that the bytecode is almost always contained in files on the filesystem is an implementation detail.  The classpath you pass to the `java` command tells it *where* to look for classes, and then the main class argument tells it which class to use.

(It's different for `javac`, because this program specifically does take source *files* and compiles them into bytecode.)

Comment: It might be useful to mention that the code could be in a JAR or elsewhere on the classpath.

Answer (score 6):

You don't pass a file name to the java command either. You pass it a fully qualified class name. Something like `com.yourcompany.yourapp.Main`. Java then finds the .class file for this class name, by looking into all the directories and jar files in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation detail. The Java class loader system can extended by custom code to make it behave differently. For example, some companies have written encrypted class loaders that are capable of decrypting and loading encrypted class files on the fly. You could hypothetically create a similar system that bundles a bunch of classes together into something resembling a .NET assembly instead of a Jar file (which is really just a zip file).

Answer (score 1):

when you execute "**`java test.class`**"

You get either

> *Could not find or load main class test.class*

or

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/class*

This is because "`java`" in "`java test.class`" is `jvm`. It looks for main method in class called "`class`" instead of "`test`". Dot in "`java test.class`" has a significant meaning. So how `jvm` looks at "`java test.class`", in a package called "`test`" it looks for a java class named "`class`".

```
*test.class*

*test* - package name

*class* - java filename
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Simple enough to understand. Detailed enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarise everything to the details,

when one does

```
java filename.java
```

s/he actually runs the java compiler and converts the code to instructions that a JVM understands.

Now when one runs

```
javac main_file
```

s/he invokes the JVM to run the entire project whose main method is found in the class **main_file**

This **main_file** is actually the fully qualified name of the class i.e. if I have a project ProjectX and this main class is in package **src.java.hello.main**,
You should run the command

```
java src.java.hello.main.main_file
```

Hence this `.` is actually a reserved thing at JVM end and we cannot give `.class` as part of the argument to the **java** command.

Answer (score -1):

The Javac compiler creates file called Xyz.class (Here Xyz is FileName)
that contains the byte version of the program
Java Bytecode is nothing but intermediate Representation of Your Program that contains instruction the Java interpreter will execute.
thus, the output of javac is not code that can be directly executed

in short, javac keyword is used for the Compile the Java program
if we Use .class with javac (Already compiled File .class File) then How can compile already compile file

so Valid Syntax is:
Javac Xyz.java  (Compile the Java Program)
java Xyz   (Run the Java Program)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You simply miss the point that `java` is not invoked to run a FILE, but a CLASS. And class names do not contain the .class extension of file names.