# Run java compiled class in JRE and ERROR: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux

I have a linux system where I have JRE installed in my /usr/lib/jvm/java1.7/jre/bin

I am trying to find the heap size of the java process running on this system using this JRE.
 I have written the following complied and trying to run it. 
 My Java class:

```
public class GetHeapSize {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Get the jvm heap size.
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

        //Print the jvm heap size.
        System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);
    }
}
```

I have both my .java and .class in the same directory. I have compiled the code on other machine [ which should not matter ]

When I run at command prompt

```
/home/codesrc>java GetHeapSize.class
Error: Could not find or load main class GetHeapSize.class
```

Can some one please suggest what am I doing wrong.
For just in case needed:

```
/home/codesrc>java -version
              java version "1.7.0_09"
              Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
              Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run java classname

java GetHeapSize

Comment: Thanks Shriram, it worked. Can you please explain me why it does not need the .class

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the `java` command is looking for a class name, and `GetHeapSize.class` isn't a valid class name in Java.

Comment: Hope it helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703461/why-dont-we-use-the-class-extension-with-java-command