# Why .class is not used with 'java' command?

Tags: java, bytecode, .class-file

While compiling a Java class from command line with `javac`, `.java` is used, however `.class` is not used while trying to run the `main` method in a class with the `java` command.

For example, for compiling a class named *HelloWorld* we use `javac HelloWorld.java`, however to run that same class (supposing it has the main method), we write `java HelloWorld` and not `java HelloWorld.class`. Why is this so? The generated `.class` file has the bytecode for the same class, but still only the name is passed.

Comment: Because it takes a class name, not a filename...

Comment: It just doesn't, OK?!

Comment: the class might be found in a subdirectory, a jar-file, anywhere where the `class-path` points to, the name identifies the class and not the location

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't we use the .class extension with "java" command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703461/why-dont-we-use-the-class-extension-with-java-command)

Answer (score 2):

As the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/) of `java` says:

**SYNOPSIS**

```
java [ options ] class [ argument...  ]
java [ options ] -jar file.jar
```

**PARAMETERS**

```
options    Command-line options.
class      Name of the class to be invoked.
file.jar   Name  of the jar file to be invoked.  Used only with the -jar option.
argument   Argument passed to the main function.
```

Notice, the `class` part, so you are passing a class name to `java`, not a class file.

Comment: Thats right @meskobalazs, however my particular confusion is still related to why Java does not allow passing `.class` file with `java` command. I mean this `.class` file still has the bytecode for that same class whose name we are passing with the `java` command.